# An error occurred during the login process

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, .net-core

```
Server=DESKTOP-4P98T57;Encrypt =True; Integrated Security = True;Trusted_Connection=SSPI;Initial Catalog=namedatabase;TrustServerCertificate=True; Persist Security Info=true;User ID=sa;Password=123456;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

Hi.
It is my connection string and when I run update-database command this error showed :

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
> error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is
> not trusted.)

I set TrustServerCertificate=true and Encrypt tested by true or false . I also checked Trust Server Certificate  in SQL server.

I use Visual Studio 2022

I set TrustServerCertificate=true and Encrypt tested by true or false . I also checked Trust Server Certificate  in SQL server.

I use Visual Studio 2022 and .Net7

Comment: Have you added the authority certificate into your client's certificate store ? It sounds like SQL server is using a real certificate, not a self-signed one ?

Comment: @Madhatter Since OP has set [TrustServerCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.trustservercertificate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) to true, the authority shouldn't even be getting checked.

Comment: OP, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58150761/2791540)

Comment: @JohnWu You're absolutely right, it should bypass chain certificate validation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75871940/sql-certificate-chain-was-issued-by-an-authority-that-is-not-trusted)